# Подгрузка данных Ajax-ом

Tags: ajax

Здравствуйте.

Имеется на странице 2 select-а. При выборе данных в 1 select, необходимо доставать данные из БД.

Как это осуществить, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: полно же готовых вариантов в нете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это осуществить так: послать ajax запрос на сервер для выборки из бд, сервер выбирает нужные данные и присылает тебе ответ (json,xml...) который ты при необходимости парсишь и вставляешь в нужное тебе место. 
Простейший пример ajax запроса:

```
 $.ajax({
        url:    '/ajax.php?act=ajax_jquery_post',
        type:   'POST',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', //Тип передаваемых данных
        data:   'text='+$('#text').val()+'&id=282&c=w',
            //а это, собственно, данные (произвольные)
        success: function(response){
          alert('Данные отправлены! Сервер вернул ответ: ' + response);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax(
{
// параметры
// код который отсылает на сервер данные из селекта и разбирает данные полученные от сервера.
}
)
```